# Please allow us to add a bounty on a documentation entry

Tags: feature-request, bounty, documentation

There are some entries in documentation that may end up being so important and so widely-read that it would make sense to be able to put a bounty on their improvement.

Please allow us to put bounty on some documentation entries in order to highlight and push for improvement of the entry.

Obviously the community nature of the entries created makes it difficult to choose the awarding of the bounty, so the strategy for who to award the bounty *to* might be slightly more complicated.

Comment: You need a lot more detail. How exactly would this work? I assume you're targeting examples, so how would it be awarded? Do you choose someone who edited the post during your period? How would auto-awarding work if they never came back? Or is this simply a thing so you can award reputation to someone for excellent work, which might I add, is **not** the original intention of the bounty system, and we likely would not implement it if users were only interested in using it for rep transfers.

Comment: @animuson Hmmm, well, you seem to be speaking to the use case, which seems almost identical to the use case on StackOverflow.  How is this for a use case: I just came across a documentation entry that so pains me, but needs so much work, that I would like to hack off some of my fake internet points in order to bring greater visibility to a problem with it... ...my personal objective there would be to try to push for a better outcome on the documentation entry.

Comment: @animuson Use case would be maybe (for example) encountering barely documented functionality/functionality not showing a coherent example how to use it together in the original documentation. Then you could put a bounty on a new topic request. To do rep transfers, I think, normal answers can already be misused well enough… Allowing bounties on documentation won't make any difference there.

Comment: How about putting the bounty on a topic/improvement request, and awarding it when the request is marked as handled?

Comment: @animuson see my answer

Comment: *poke to frontpage*

Answer (score 2):

## *In more detail...*

## *How?*

1. **Allow bounties on specifically tags, topics, and examples**

   - *Tags* - for empty or abandoned tags that need more documentation in general
   - *Topics* - for critical topics the bounty giver believes are critical
   - *Examples* - for widely read examples that are messy, wayward, and unorganized*
2. **Allow the bounty giver to choose who to give the bounty to**
3. **Allow the bounty giver to coarsely divide the bounty reward**

   - This encourages people to contribute, even if they have seen another user make major contributions that would probably otherwise cause the bounty to be awarded to that other user.
   - This makes Documentation a more collaborative place.
   - Documentation does not have the binary nature of Q&A.
4. **Prevent premature bounty giving by enforcing a fixed bounty time**

   - Even if a user's contributions satisfy the bounty giver
   - *Again*, documentation does not have the binary nature of Q&A.

---

## *Why?*

From the original +200 meta discussion, [*Docs is broken: Writing Docs we Actually Need*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331946/docs-is-broken-writing-docs-we-actually-need):

> **The current system rewards writing documentation that is already covered by the official docs. Meanwhile, popular libraries without good official docs are undercontributed.** The system is broken, and it needs fixing.

[A few](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331963/1459669) [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331987/1459669) have proposed the aforementioned solution.

Users who find that official documentation is poor and the Stack Overflow version is likewise are the ones who will invest in setting bounties. The more popular the object lacking documentation, the more bounties it receives, and the more necessary better documentation. **In essence, supply matches demand.**

I hope this is more convincing than the original question.

---

## Footnotes

<sub>*this is an enevitable part of the incremental, distributed development experienced by popular posts. Almost all popular examples show these symptoms.</sub>